# ¿Cómo cambiar las filas de una variable según una condición?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un `dataframe` con una columna "roa/WACC" sobre la industria hotelera. Quiero cambiar los datos de esta columna con un 1 si el dato es positivo y un 0 si es negativo, es decir cambiar de una variable numerica a una variable binaria. He probado con un bucle for y  creando una lista vacia pero da error:

```
#CAMBAIR VARIABLE Y A 0 1 DEPENDIENDO SI ES POSITIVO O NEGATIVO
cosa=[]
for i in ROAWACC19[1]:
    if row['ROA/WACC'] <= 0  :
        cosa.append(0)
    else:
      cosa.append(1)

print(cosa)
```

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), [ask], [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En pandas casi nunca necesitas escribir bucles. Si necesitas aplicar una misma operación a todos los datos de una columna (por ejemplo, comparar con 0 en tu caso), puedes escribirlo en una sola operación, como esta:

```
cosa = df["ROA/WACC"] >= 0
```

Eso hace que pandas automáticamente haga lo siguiente:

- Iterar por cada fila de la columna "ROA/WACC"
- Comparar cada elemento con 0 (lo que le dará como resultado `True` o `False`)
- Crear una variable de tipo `pandas.Series` (que es el tipo de las columnas) para ir almacenando los resultados.

La sintaxis "sin bucles" no sólo es mucho más compacta (fácil de leer y menos proclive a errores), sino también mucho más veloz, pues es Pandas  quien itera por las filas y no tu código python. Pandas está escrito en C y optimizado para este tipo de cosas, por lo que siempre será mucho más rápido.

Al final, la variable `cosa` será una Serie compuesta de `True` y `False` como  la siguiente (dependiendo, claro está, de los valores que hubiera en la columna ROA/WACC y de si eran o no positivos):

```
>>> print(cosa)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8     True
9     True
Name: ROA/WACC, dtype: bool
```

A partir de aqui puedes si quieres asignar este resultado a otra columna de tu dataframe (por ejemplo: `df["result"] = cosa`) o utilizarlo en la forma que necesites.

En tu pregunta especificabas que querías que el resultado fuese 0 o 1. Es posible que te sirva también que el resultado sea booleano, lo que en general tiene más sentido, pero si realmente necesitas que sean ceros y unos, basta convertir el resultado:

```
>>> print(cosa.astype(int))
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    1
Name: ROA/WACC, dtype: int64
```

Y si no quieres que sea una Serie sino una mera lista como la que intentabas construir en tu pregunta, también puedes obtenerla así:

```
>>> print(cosa.astype(int).tolist())
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Lo puedes lograr fácilmente al utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

Como no pusiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico y tendrás que adaptar el código a tus necesidades.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creamos un dataframe genérico con 10 filas
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randint(-10, 10, 10)})

# Aplicamos una función lambda para devolver 1 en caso de que sea positivo
# y 0 en caso de que sea negativo
df['col2'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>=0 else 0)
print(df)
```

**Nota:** Cree una nueva columna para que comprobaras el resultado pero puedes asignarlo a la misma columna sin problemas.

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   col  col2
0    0     1
1    8     1
2   -9     0
3    7     1
4    1     1
5   -7     0
6    0     1
7   -4     0
8    5     1
9  -10     0
```